# Checking file size

Tags: bash, find

I want to check the file size in a shell script. I am trying to check if the file in a specific directory exceeds 2 GB, i.e., 2,147,483,648 bytes.

How can I easily do this in a shell script?

I have the following two files:

```
-rw-rw-rw-    1 op       general  1977591120 Jul 02 08:27 abc
-rw-rw-rw-    1 op       general  6263142976 Jul 01 18:39 xyz
```

When I run `find . -size +2047MB`, I get both the files as output

```
./abc
./xyz
```

I expect only *xyz* in the output size it is ~6 GB and *abc* is slightly less than ~2 GB . What can be the reason for both files showing up in the output?

Comment: Have you tried just 'find -size 2047M'?

Comment: Related: *[How can I check the size of a file using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920333/)*

Answer (score 3):

### How to find files in a specific directory

#### What *man* says

> ```
> -size n[cwbkMG]
>
>         File uses n units of space.  The following suffixes can be used:
>
>         `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
>         `c'    for bytes
>         `w'    for two-byte words
>         `k'    for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
>         `M'    for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)
>         `G'    for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)
> ```

#### Examples

##### Find files larger than 2 GB in the current directory, but don't look in subdirectories

`find . -size +2G -maxdepth 1`

##### Output it with the `ls -dils` format

`find . -size +2G -maxdepth 1 -ls`

#### Other comments

I'm surprised your `MB` didn't kick out an error.  Example: `` find: invalid -size type `B' ``

This may be due to your distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Compare:

```
stat -f "%z bytes   %N"  ./*     # FreeBSD stat                                         syntax highlighter fix */

find . -size +$((2*1024*1024*1024))c    #  man 1 find | less -p '-size'
```

Comment: This helps to find if the file present in a directory is bigger or not. If I know the file which I am checking, how can I check the size of that file in the shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Try `find . -size +2047M` without the B. This seems to work in subdirectories too.

Comment: What platform and filesystem are you using?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that *[find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix))* is including the file system overhead and any unused space in the cluster occupied by the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `+2G` instead of `MB`...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the `du` command.

Use the -h option like... `du yourfilename.ext -h` and you'll get something humanly readable.

Comment: important side note, du uses 1024 byte blocks, so 1KB blocks. you can do the math from there to find GB size and whatnot. Hope this helps!