# How can I check the size of a file using Bash?

Tags: bash

I've got a script that checks for 0-size, but I thought there must be an easier way to check for file sizes instead.  I.e. `file.txt` is normally 100 kB; how can I make a script check if it is less than 90 kB (including 0), and make it [Wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) a new copy because the file is corrupt in this case?

What I'm currently using...

```
if [ -n file.txt ]
then
  echo "everything is good"
else
  mail -s "file.txt size is zero, please fix. " myemail@gmail.com < /dev/null
  # Grab wget as a fallback
  wget -c https://www.server.org/file.txt -P /root/tmp --output-document=/root/tmp/file.txt
  mv -f /root/tmp/file.txt /var/www/file.txt
fi
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Related (getting it, not checking): *[Portable way to get file size (in bytes) in the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815329/)*

Comment: Title of question should be changed. This is about detecting zero size files, not about checking the size of a file.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

`[ -n file.txt ]` doesn't check its size. It checks that the string `file.txt` is non-zero length, so it will always succeed.

If you want to say "size is non-zero", you need `[ -s file.txt ]`.

To get a file's size, you can use `wc -c` to get the size (file length) in bytes:

```
file=file.txt
minimumsize=90000
actualsize=$(wc -c <"$file")
if [ $actualsize -ge $minimumsize ]; then
    echo size is over $minimumsize bytes
else
    echo size is under $minimumsize bytes
fi
```

In this case, it sounds like that's what you want.

But FYI, if you want to know how much disk space the file is using, you could use `du -k` to get the size (disk space used) in kilobytes:

```
file=file.txt
minimumsize=90
actualsize=$(du -k "$file" | cut -f 1)
if [ $actualsize -ge $minimumsize ]; then
    echo size is over $minimumsize kilobytes
else
    echo size is under $minimumsize kilobytes
fi
```

If you need more control over the output format, you can also look at `stat`.  On Linux, you'd start with something like `stat -c '%s' file.txt`, and on [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) and [Mac OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X), something like `stat -f '%z' file.txt`.

Comment: Why `du -b "$file" | cut -f 1` instead of `stat -c '%s' "$file"`? Or `stat --printf="%s" "$file"`?

Comment: Only because it's more portable.  BSD and Linux `stat`  have different flags.

Comment: One advantage to the 'du' solution is that it can (with the -s option) also be used on directories.

Comment: Try `wc -c`.  Or `BLOCKSIZE=1 du`.  Or if you don't mind using kilobytes, `du -k`.

Comment: I had to modify it to `... | cut -d' ' -f1` to get it to work on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Mikepote Yes, now I'm using `wc`, the `-d ' '` is needed, thanks.

Comment: Use `wc -c < "$file"` (note the `<`), in which case you don't need the `| cut ...` part (which, as posted, doesn't work on OSX). The minimum `BLOCKSIZE` value for `du` on OSX is `512`.

Comment: On Mac OS X (Mavericks), I found that cut handles each individual space as a field separator.  I favoured awk instead: `... | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: @paddy With `wc`, there should only be one space.  With `du`, there should be a tab.  But I'll use mklement0's suggestion for `wc` to remove the `cut` entirely.

Comment: @Mikel The problem I had was that there are numerous leading spaces.  It looks like the number is output with 8-character width, as in `printf( "%8d", size );`.  Those leading spaces are all picked up as field separators by `cut`.  Your updated solution using standard input without `cut` appears to be more portable.

Comment: @Mikel how to do this process each 20 seconds so i can check incrementation of file size so on?

Comment: Is it not inefficient to read the file to determine it's size? I think stat will not read the file to see it's size.

Comment: It also seems that `wc -c` uses optimized approach [fstat and seek](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16640/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-bash-script#comment634607_16668) to determine the file size, but this obviously only works when given a file to work witt, not a stream. So to avoid the cut operation on wc output the whole file is read through to know it's size.

Comment: @PetriSirkkala On my Linux system, `wc -c <filename` also uses `fstat` and `seek`?  Note that `fstat` takes an fd, not a pathname.

Comment: While the implementation for `wc -c` indeed does use `seek`, it still isn't the purpose of this tool - as it reads the rest of the bytes on stream. The `stat` solution by Daniel C. Sobral is the correct way to do. `du` also has a `--bytes` option that is equally useful.

Comment: As I said in my comment above from 2013, I suggested this approach because the way to run `stat` is different on different operating systems.

Answer (score 46):

[`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) can also check the file size. Some methods are definitely better: using `-s` to find out whether the file is empty or not is easier than anything else if that's all you want. And if you want to *find* files of a size, then `find` is certainly the way to go.

I also like `du` a lot to get file size in kb, but, for bytes, I'd use `stat`:

```
size=$(stat -f%z $filename) # BSD stat

size=$(stat -c%s $filename) # GNU stat?
```

Comment: `stat` is a great idea, but on CentOS this is what worked for me: `size=$(stat -c%s $filename)`

Comment: The difference between GNU and BSD is what, unfortunately, makes this alternative a bit less attractive. :(

Comment: stat can be misleading if the file is sparse.   You could use the blocks reported by stat to calculate space used.

Comment: @AjithAntony That's an interesting point which did not occur to me. I can see `stat` being the _right_ thing in some situations, and sparse files are not relevant in most situations, though certainly not all.

Comment: du -b <filename> will do the bytes.

Answer (score 21):

An alternative solution with [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) and double parenthesis:

```
FILENAME=file.txt
SIZE=$(du -sb $FILENAME | awk '{ print $1 }')

if ((SIZE<90000)) ; then
    echo "less";
else
    echo "not less";
fi
```

Comment: Nice, but won't work on OSX, where `du` doesn't support `-b`. (It may be a conscious style choice, but just to mention the alternative: you can omit the `$` prefix inside `(( ... ))` when referencing variables: `((SIZE<90000))`)

Comment: Actually it was an edit from a previous user who thought it was wrong to omit the `$`

Comment: @fstab, you may ommit `awk` by using `read` (`bash` internal command): `read SIZE _ <<<$(du -sb "$FILENAME")`

Answer (score 16):

If your `find` handles this syntax, you can use it:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "file.txt" -size -90k
```

This will output `file.txt` to stdout if and only if the size of `file.txt` is less than 90k. To execute a script `script` if `file.txt` has a size less than 90k:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "file.txt" -size -90k -exec script \;
```

Comment: +1, but to also make it work on OSX, you need an explicit target directory argument, e.g.: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "file.txt" -size -90k`

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking for just the size of a file:

```
cat $file | wc -c
```

Sample output:

> 203233

Comment: This might be the shortest workable answer, but it is probably also the slowest. :)

Comment: Yes, but certainly economically superior: Cost of engineering time > Cost of computation time

Comment: `wc -c "$file"` was given as an answer in 2011 (three years ago). Yes, `wc -c "$file"` has the problem that it outputs the file name as well as the character count, so the early answers added a command to separate out the count. But `wc -c < "$file"`, which fixes that problem, was added as a comment in May 2014. Your answer is equivalent to that, except it adds a [“useless use of `cat`”](http://superuser.com/q/323060/354511). Also, you should quote all shell variable references unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: You can make this more efficient by using head -c instead of cat.if [ $(head -c 90000 $file | wc -c) -lt 90000 ] ; then echo "File is smaller than 90k" ; fi . Tested on CentOS, so it may or may not work on BSD or OSX.

Answer (score 6):

This works in both Linux and [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS):

```
function filesize
{
    local file=$1
    size=`stat -c%s $file 2>/dev/null` # Linux
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $size
        return 0
    fi

    eval $(stat -s $file) # macOS
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $st_size
        return 0
    fi

    return -1
}
```

Comment: [The default shell in macOS is now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina#Removed_or_changed_components) [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (from 2019).

Answer (score 4):

For getting the file size in both Linux and Mac OS X (and presumably other [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) systems), there are not many options, and most of the ones suggested here will only work on one system.

Given `f=/path/to/your/file`,

**what does work in both Linux and Mac**'s Bash:

```
size=$( perl -e 'print -s shift' "$f" )
```

or

```
size=$( wc -c "$f" | awk '{print $1}' )
```

The other answers work fine in Linux, but not in Mac:

- `du` doesn't have a `-b` option in Mac, and the BLOCKSIZE=1 trick doesn't work ("minimum blocksize is 512", which leads to a wrong result)
- `cut -d' ' -f1` doesn't work because on Mac, the number may be right-aligned, padded with spaces in front.

So if you need something flexible, it's either `perl`'s `-s` operator , or `wc -c` piped to `awk '{print $1}'` (awk will ignore the leading white space).

And of course, regarding the rest of your original question, use the `-lt` (or `-gt`) operator:

`if [ $size -lt $your_wanted_size ]; then`, etc.

Comment: +1; if you know you'll only be using the size in an _arithmetic_ context (where leading whitespace is ignored), you can simplify to `size=$(wc -c < "$f")` (note the `<`, which causes `wc` to only report a number). Re comparison: don't forget the more "bash-ful" `if (( size < your_wanted_size )); then ...` (and also `[[ $size -lt $your_wanted_size ]]`).

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
python -c 'import os; print (os.path.getsize("... filename ..."))'
```

It is portable, for all flavours of Python, and it avoids variation in `stat` dialects.

Comment: But the question was about checking for a file size threshold, e.g. 100 KB, not just getting the file size.

Answer (score 3):

Based on gniourf_gniourf’s answer,

```
find "file.txt" -size -90k
```

will write `file.txt` to stdout if and only if the size of `file.txt` is less than 90K, and

```
find "file.txt" -size -90k -exec command \;
```

will execute the command *`command`* if `file.txt` has a size less than 90K. 
I have tested this on Linux. 
From [`find(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find),

> …  Command-line arguments following (the `-H`, `-L` and `-P` options) are taken to be names of ***files or*** directories to be examined, up to the first argument that begins with ‘-’, …

(emphasis added).

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -l $file | awk '{print $6}'
```

assuming that ls command reports filesize at column #6

Comment: But the question was about checking for a file size threshold, e.g. 100 KB, not just getting the file size.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `du`'s `--threshold` for this. Not sure if this option is available in all versions of `du` but it is implemented in GNU's version.

Quoting from [du(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/du)'s manual:

```
-t, --threshold=SIZE
       exclude entries smaller than SIZE if positive, or entries greater
       than SIZE if negative
```

Here's my solution, using `du --threshold=` for OP's use case:

```
THRESHOLD=90k
if [[ -z "$(du --threshold=${THRESHOLD} file.txt)" ]]; then
    mail -s "file.txt size is below ${THRESHOLD}, please fix. " myemail@gmail.com < /dev/null
    mv -f /root/tmp/file.txt /var/www/file.txt
fi
```

The advantage of that, is that `du` can accept an argument to that option in a known format - either human as in `10K`, `10MiB` or what ever you feel comfortable with - you don't need to manually convert between formats / units since `du` handles that.

For reference, here's the explanation on this `SIZE` argument from the man page:

```
The SIZE argument is an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 
10*1024). Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,... (powers
of 1000). Binary prefixes can be used, too: KiB=K, MiB=M, and so on.
```

Comment: +1 Excellent option. Unfortunately some of us are stuck with older versions of `du` that don't support it. The `--threshold` option was added in coreutils 8.21, [released in 2013](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7505).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if you're on a Mac, do this:
`stat -f %z "/Users/Example/config.log"`

That's it!

Comment: But the question was about checking for a file size threshold, e.g. 100 KB, not just getting the file size.