# How to check if the size of a file or a directory is larger than a value in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, comparison, backup

I want to write a short backup script in Bash that lets me choose a directory that I want to save, and then compress it. I've got that done.

Next, I wanted to make it so that I could compare the size of the files that are to be copied. I used `du -b /example/directory | cut -f1` . That got me the sizes of folders in that directory, without their names. But I can't really compare it to a value using the *if* statement, because it isn't an integer statement.

This is my code so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Which folders to backup
backup_files="/home"

# Where to save
dest="/home/student"

# Check size of each folder
file_size=$(du -b /example/directory | cut -f1)

# Size limit
check_size=1000

# Archive name
day=$(date +%A)
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$hostname-$day.tar.gz"

# Here's the problem I have
if [ "$file_size" -le "$check_size" ]; then
    tar -vczf /$dest/$archive_file $backup_files
fi

echo "Backup finished"
```

Comment: For single files: *[How can I check the size of a file using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920333/)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-s` (summarize) option to your `du`. Without it, you are returning the sizes of every subdirectory which makes your final size comparison fail.

Change:

```
file_size=$(du -b /example/directory | cut -f1)
```

to:

```
file_size=$(du -bs /example/directory | cut -f1)
```

If you want to test each individual object, do something like:

```
du -b /example/directory |
    while read size name
    do
        if [ "$size" -le "$limit" ]; then
            # do something...
        else
            # do something else - object too big...
        fi       
    done
```

Comment: Yes, but that would sum up the size of all subdirectories into one, but I want to check their individual sizes so if, for example, one of them is over 10 mb, and my limit is 12 mb, then that directory is omitted.

Comment: @JRFerguson, can I use `-h` for `du`? For example, `if [ 1.4G -le 700M]`.